# Pass own Jenkins Build number format

Tags: jenkins

I want to pass my own build number format to my jenkins job.

i am able to change build number in my required format. the latest changed number i want to pass it as build number

I am using below pipeline for my required build number. it is not working as expected

```
pipeline {
    agent {label "agentname" }
    parameters 
    {
        string(name: 'RELEASE_VERSION', defaultValue: '', description: '')
    }
    stages {
        stage ('TEST1') {
           steps {  
            sh '''
            RELEASE_VERSION=`echo "$RELEASE_VERSION" | awk -F. '{ OFS=FS; print $1, $2, $3, $4 $5 }'`
            echo "$RELEASE_VERSION"
            '''
            script{
                currentBuild.displayName = "${RELEASE_VERSION}"
                currentBuild.description = ""
                }
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Input RELEASE_VERSION = 1.1.00200.08050.100

output build number format
1.1.00200.08050.100

Required build number format
1.1.00200.08050100

Comment: @Ian W: the output which i am getting with this, should be my build number (RELEASE_VERSION=`echo "$RELEASE_VERSION" | awk -F. '{ OFS=FS; print $1, $2, $3, $4 $5 }'`). with above pipeline i am getting build number as 1.1.00200.08050.100 but i looking for 1.1.00200.08050100 this build number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as expected as the scope of the variable inside the shell step to limited to that only. You need to remove that current shell step and replace it with this.

```
pipeline {
    agent {label "agentname" }
    parameters
    {
        string(name: 'RELEASE_VERSION', defaultValue: '', description: '')
    }
    stages {
        stage ('TEST1') {
           steps {
            script{
                def RELEASE_VERSION = sh(script: "echo ${RELEASE_VERSION} | awk -F. '{ OFS=FS; print \$1, \$2, \$3, \$4 \$5 }'", returnStdout: true).trim()
                println (RELEASE_VERSION)
                currentBuild.displayName = "${RELEASE_VERSION}"
                currentBuild.description = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting space at the end of output(NEW_RELEASE_VERSION), need to remove that. here is my output + echo 1.2.0020.0610.1
+ awk -F. '{ OFS=FS; print $1, $2, $3, $4 $5 }'
[Pipeline] echo
1.2.0020.06101

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo '1.2.0020.06101
'
1.2.0020.06101

Comment: @rizwana I have updated my answer; please check now. If all ok please do accept and upvote. I have even changed the variable name as per your original script.